# Array Object index properties

Tags: javascript

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for(var prop in a){
    console.log(prop); // '0', '1', '2'
}

console.log([] instanceof Object, a['0']); //true, 'a'
```

Based on the code above, is it correct to assume that when a new array is created, each index is set as a property on its corresponding base object? Is this specified somewhere?

Comment: Arrays _are_ objects; there is no "base object".

Comment: @SLaks I think he mean native object.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No such thing exists.

Comment: @SLaks There are Native objects in js just as there're host objects.( or am i not getting your point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT use this construct:

```
for(var prop in a)
```

for iterating the elements of an array.  That iterates all iterable properties of the object AND all array elements, not just array elements.  Array elements should be iterated with either this style:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    // a[i]
}
```

or (in modern browsers):

```
a.forEach(function(value, index) {
    // use value here
});
```

---

An array is also an object.  It can have properties besides the array elements.  It is correct that all array elements can be accessed like a property with a string key, but that is still not the desired way to iterate only array elements.

For example, you could do this:

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
a.whatever = 3;

for(var prop in a){
    console.log(prop); // '0', '1', '2', 'whatever'
}
```

Comment: I know that I shouldn't. It doesn't seem to iterate the actual _elements_, but the properties that are added to the object. To access the actual element, I would have to do something like `a[prop]`, rather than `prop`. Since an `Array` is an `Object`, I want to know if it's safe to assume that the properties are added to the object itself when creating a new array?

Comment: @Johan - it is safe to assume that an array element can be accessed with property notation and that the `for ... in` notation will include array elements (in addition to properties).   But, it's an array element.  No "property" is added to the object perse.  It's an array element and there are subtle differences - they are not the same thing.  For example, only array elements are included in `.length`.

Comment: If no properties are added, then why can I access `a['0']`, which which essentially is the same as `a.0` (which obviously wouldn't compile)?

Comment: @Johan - because the array supports accessing an array element as either `a['0']` or as `a[0]`.  I think you're just arguing semantics here.  Properties and array elements are not exactly the same thing and if you're thinking about writing code that assumes they are the same thing, that is probably a bad idea.  Can you turn this into a practical question rather than a theoretical one?  What issues are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: There's no actual problem, I'm just curious about the behavior. Since a `for .. in` loop on `{a: 1}` returns `a` which is the property, it sounds to me like `1` is added as a property on `[1]`, since the `for .. in` returns `1`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Johan - you're just arguing semantics here and I'm not following to what end.  An array element can be accessed with "property-like" syntax.  No extra "property" thing is created for every array element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe it's part of the spec: an array is an object, and the names of it's properties are the indices converted to a string. It's kind of ugly.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for answering the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

for ( ... in ... ) is for looping through the properties and methods of an object.

You want to use the classic for (i=0; i < length; i++) for an array like you are using.